# Getting a variable from a FXML to an imported FXML

Tags: javafx, fxml

I'm currently doing a Java (+ using MySQL) application for my studies : an Database for an Hopital

I code my interface using JavaFX.
I have a Main FXML(for the general view) where I have tabs and in each tab I import another FXML using (fx:include). So that each module of my application has his own Controller and own designed View.

How can pass a variable from the main Controller to the others controllers?

Thanks!
Edit : Let me show you my code

So first there it's the class in which I load my fxml (I have on window of Connexion first and if the informations required for the connexion are ok I load the fxml Main with the main interface) And I set the connexion (THE VARIABLE I NEED TO SEND) that I got from my fxml Connexion to the FXML Main

```
public class MainApp extends Application {

private Stage primaryStage;
private Connection conn;
MainController controllermain = new MainController();
//ConnexionController controllerconnex;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    this.primaryStage.setTitle("BASE DE L'HOPITAL DU ZOB");
    showConnexion();
}

public void showConnexion() {
    try {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("Connexion.fxml"));
        Parent page = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(page);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        ConnexionController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setMainApp(this);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void showMainApp(Connection conn) {
    try {
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("Main.fxml"));
        AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(page);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
        this.conn = conn;

        controllermain = loader.getController();
        controllermain.setMainApp(this);
        controllermain.setConnexion(conn); // I want to send the variable conn to the others

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Then this is my Main Controller and you can see that I get the variable connexion only with the set method and then I can send it the the other controller

```
public class MainController implements Initializable {


private MainApp mainApp;
private Button retour;
protected Connection conn;


FXML AchorPane ;

   public MainController() {
}

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

}    


 public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
    this.mainApp = mainApp;


}

 public void setConnexion(Connection conn){

 this.conn=conn;

     }
public void handleRetour(){
                       mainApp.showConnexion();


    }
 }     


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a reference to the controller corresponding to the included fxml in the controller corresponding to the "main" fxml. You can do this using the [Nested Controllers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#nested_controllers) mechanism.

Briefly, if you have a "main" fxml with a `<fx:include>` tag, add an `fx:id` to the `<fx:include>`:

Main.fxml:

```
<!-- imports etc -->

<!-- root element, e.g. BorderPane -->
<BorderPane fx:controller="com.example.MainController" xmlns="..." ... >

<!-- ... -->

<fx:include source="tab.fxml" fx:id="tab" />

<!-- ... -->
</BorderPane>
```

Then in the `MainController` you can inject the controller from the included fxml using `@FXML`. The rule is that you append the word `"Controller"` to the `fx:id` used in the `fx:include`. For example, if the controller class for tab.fxml is `TabController`, given the `fx:id` is `tab`, you would do:

```
public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private TabController tabController ;

    private Connection conn ;

    // other injected fields, etc...

    public void setConnexion(Connection conn) {
        this.conn = conn ;
        // pass Connection to TabController:
        tabController.setConnexion(conn);
    }
}
```

Now just define a `setConnexion(...)` method in `TabController` (if you haven't already) to receive the `Connection` object (and update anything it needs to update as a result).

Comment: Yes thanks a lot! But if I don't have the variable I want to set before the initialize method is called it's still possible or there isn't another way?

Comment: The `tabController` field in the example code is an instance variable, so it will stay in scope for the lifetime of the `MainController`. So whenever the variable you need is set, you can pass it to the `tabController`. (For example, if it is set in an event handler, you can reference the `tabController` in the event handler.) You could also define [JavaFX properties](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107) in both controllers, and create bindings between them... If you edit your question to be more specific about when the values are available, I can update the answer.

Comment: See updated question; you just need to access the nested controller from the `setConnexion(...)` method.

Comment: I did what you advised me but I get a NullPointerException when the other controller use a fonction using the conn variable..

Comment: That's probably a separate question... I guess I would ask if you are referencing the connection in the nested controller before it is set by the `setConnexion(...)` method. E.g. you won't be able to reference it in the `initialize()` method because `setConnexion(...)` won't have been called at that point. Any initialization that depends on the connection should be done in `setConnexion(...)`.

Comment: In that case I would post a new question, with enough code to see what is happening and when the relevant pieces are initialized. (Also identify the line in the code that is generating the `NullPointerException`.)

Comment: I use my variable after having called the SetConnexion method.
I don't get what you mean there " you won't be able to reference it in the initialize() method because setConnexion(...) won't have been called at that point" ? Should i call something in my initialize method of the imported fxml?

Comment: No, I meant *don't* reference the connection in the `initialize()` method of the included fxml. But it sounds like you already have that correct.

Comment: Ok. so you agree that in my imported fxml I just had to add the method setConnection and thats all?

Comment: <fx:include source="tab.fxml" fx:id="tab" /> I don't see why I have to put an idea because I don't use it in my code after, am I wrong?

Comment: You need the fx:Id otherwise the FXMLLoader won't be able to determine the name of the variable to inject the controller.

Comment: ok but where  ? because in your code you only use "tab" in the fxml but I don't see in the java document? Maybe it's my probleme because I fixed the id in my fxml but I don't use it then in the java

Comment: Read my answer again and, if that's not clear enough, read the documentation I linked. I don't really know how to say it differently to "you append the word 'Controller' to the fx:id". So tab becomes tabController to inject the controller.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm French so I don't understand clearly all the words but now it's ! THANKS A LOT IT'S FINNALY WORKING!!!

Comment: La partie importante est: "La règle est que vous ajoutez le mot "Controller" à la fx:id utilisé dans la fx:include." Donc `fx:id="tab"` résulte en `@FXML TabController tabController;`